# Is it recommended to cache Collections.unmodifiableList() result in a field?

Tags: java, performance, caching, collections, immutability

Which one is the recommended approach:

```
private final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Object> getListView() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

or

```
private final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Object> listView = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

public List<Object> getListView() {
    return listView;
}
```

The latter saves on object creation, but is it worth the effort?

Comment: What is your use case? How often are you going to call the `getListView()`? What are other circumstances? In general, your first approach (not caching) looks better, however there *might* be situations when the second one (caching) makes also sense.

Comment: Caution:  the contents of an unmodifiable list can still change, if your class changes the underlying ArrayList—being unmodifiable only means that callers of the method won’t have the ability to change it.  A solution to this is to return an unmodifiable List that wraps a defensive copy, that is, `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(list))`.

Comment: @VGR the term “View” in the name usually indicates that the result in not decoupled from the source, so I’d assume that the OP is aware of that. That’s especially true for the second variant, which wouldn’t even work without that behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating an `unmodifiableList` is an O(1) operation (essentially, it instantiates a `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList` and assings your list to a datamember).

Unless you have a **very** convincing benchmark of your special-case that shows the contrary, it probably just isn't worth the hassle of caching it.

Answer (score 3):

The second approach definitely saves you allocations and deallocations. However, the frequency of such allocations is not going to be critical to justify storing `listView` object. Consider a typical use:

```
for (Object obj : getListView()) {
    ... // Do something with each object
}
```

A single call to `getListView()` is followed by N iterations on its content, making the share of time spent creating an unmodifiable view too small to justify the effort.

In situations where `list` and `listView` are non-final there would be ab additional concern of maintaining the consistency between the two objects. I would definitely caution against caching in a class where `list` and `listView` could get "out of sync".

Comment: Not only is the iteration expected to be the expensive part, there are two iterators created behind the scenes (the original one and its unmodifiable wrapper), nobody cares about. So why should anyone care about the creation of the even cheaper list view instance…

Comment: @Holger Sure, the instance creation is no problem, but [what about equals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339692/581205)?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1** is recommended as a lazy load scenario and can save you a few resources. Also creating an `unmodifiableList` is not an expensive operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "`listView` will not be updated if `list` changes"? `listView` mirrors all the changes made in the original list, not regarding how many times you create it.

Comment: Then you may delete your answer, because it is just a duplicate of other answers, which are IMO better explained.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, the difference is hardly measurable, so I'd keep it simple. However, there are cases, when there may be a substantial difference:

```
 Collections.unmodifiableList(list).equals(Collections.unmodifiableList(list))
```

is an `O(n)` operation, as the shortcut using `==` does not work. Such a comparison may be needed, e.g., when you use the list as a cache key.

Despite that, I'd suggest to keep it simple, and only optimize, when the application needs it and the profiler shows that it may help.

Consider using Guava's `ImmutableList`, if you can.

Comment: Of course, it would be fixable within the immutable collection itself, e.g. by checking whether the other collection also is such a wrapper and delegate to something like `wrapped.equals(other.wrapped)`. It could be as simple as `boolean equals(Object other) { return other!=null && other.equals(wrapped); }` which uses the polymorphic behavior to achieve this without needing additional effort. It’s a pity that it doesn’t. By the way, in Java 8, `ArrayList` inherits `equals` from `AbstractList`, which doesn’t even check whether the sizes differ before iterating.

Comment: @Holger That's nice and following general rule "check whatever you can and then, if you made any progress, delegate to the other object ".  Concerning `ArrayList`, it didn't get fixed in [Java 10](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk10u/blob/dev/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) either, but [WOW](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~redestad/8196340/open.00/open.changeset).

Comment: Well, yes I only looked at Java 8 and Java 11, to find that in Java 8, it doesn’t have an `equals` method whereas in Java 11 (beta), it has.